# Elastic Cloud / Kibana stream cloudwatch to logs dashboard

Tags: logging, kibana, amazon-cloudwatch

So I've noticed Kibana now has a very nice 'tail' functionality for logs being streamed to ES, the logs dashboard shows lots of out of box functionality using filebeat and includes apache logs, iis and lots more.

[image: Logs setup wizard]
Currently, we stream our cloudwatch logs to specific index but I can't quite figure out how to get Kibana to use our current index, when I click "Logs" in Kibana I get "Looks like you don't have any logging indices, Let's add some!"

[image]
How do I configure our logs to appear in the Logs dashboard within Kibana?

Comment: Does my answer helps? do you have any doubts?

Comment: Hey sorry I've been away, hmm let me try that, so it's the name of the index that causes that interface to kick in?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that when you say:

> we stream our cloudwatch logs to specific index

You mean that your are pushing this information into and ElasticSearch index, if this is the case you only need to create an index in Kibana to see data, this can be done as follows:

Go to the index patterns in the management window:

[image]

And click on Create Index Pattern:

[image]

And finally, you must define a pattern that match with the index name created, in my case I am going to get the logstash indexes.

[image]

In the next step you need to define which field is going to be used as timestamp and once selected you'll have your logs imported.

Once you have the index created inside Kibana, you can go to the Discover section, select the index and check the data inside this index, test queries or even save this queries to be used in a visualization.